# Current locale on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I am looking for the right way to get the device locale on the Windows Phone 8 under C++/CX.

The following code always returns *"en"* on Windows Phone 8 emulator.

```
int ccBuf = GetLocaleInfoEx(LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT,
                            LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME,
                            buf, 9);
```

Comment: Did you test this on a real device, and if so, what's the result there? When testing this with the emulator, did you follow the steps described at [How to test region settings for Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394014.aspx)? Pay close attention to the documented behavior of **closing** and **restarting** the emulator towards the bottom.

Comment: Yes I have done as it is descripted above. Language of the device changed, but the locale was returned as en. I did have possibility to test on real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will return the language of the device in two letters format "en", "fr" etc.

```
#include <windows.h>
std::string platformGetDeviceLanguage()
{
    ULONG numLanguages = 0;
    DWORD cchLanguagesBuffer = 0;
    BOOL hr = GetUserPreferredUILanguages(MUI_LANGUAGE_NAME, &numLanguages, NULL, &cchLanguagesBuffer);

    if (hr) 
    {
        WCHAR* pwszLanguagesBuffer = new WCHAR[cchLanguagesBuffer];
        std::string lang_code = "en";
        hr = GetUserPreferredUILanguages(MUI_LANGUAGE_NAME, &numLanguages, pwszLanguagesBuffer, &cchLanguagesBuffer);
        if (hr) 
        {
            lang_code[0] = pwszLanguagesBuffer[0];
            lang_code[1] = pwszLanguagesBuffer[1];
        }
        delete[] pwszLanguagesBuffer;
        return lang_code;
    }
    return "en";
}
```